# Plot Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data. for example there are two columns. First column data is continuous. second column value is binary value(t|f). I want to plot this in a bar chart in R language. In the first column, I want group the numbers into category like 0-100, 101-200,..... then i want to plot  number of t's in y axis. I have used ggplot2 in R. But i am not clear with how to group these x axis data.

> ```
> 1  123           t
> 2  145           t
> 3  222           t
> 4  345           f
> 5  455           t
> 6  567           t
> 7  245           t
> 8  300           t
> 9  150           t
> 10 600           t
> 11 333           t
> ```

Comment: You can `cut` the data to create a grouping label. This will be a factor that you can use to do the counts using `aggregate()`.

Comment: i tried histogram. But i need the bar chart view for how many t in each interval. I am ok with plotting coding.I need to know how to split this x axis data into category 0-100, 101-200...etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here's your sample data in a data.frame

```
dd<-structure(list(V1 = 1:11, V2 = c(123L, 145L, 222L, 345L, 455L, 
567L, 245L, 300L, 150L, 600L, 333L), V3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("f", "t"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Here's a strategy for plotting

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=cut(V2, breaks=c(0,1:9*100)), weight=as.numeric(V3=="t"))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="bin") + xlab("value")
```

We define `x` and `weights` in the `aes()`. We use `cut()` to break up with numbers into ranges. Then we use `weights` to turn each value to a zero/one value that will be added together in the bins.